# How Merge 2 arrays of Dates uniquely and performant in Javascript (with jQuery, if possible)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge

i am trying to merge 2 array of Date objects uniqely, but don't get it the decent way. Here is my noob solution:

```
$old = [new Date('2012-08-01'), new Date('2012-08-02'), new Date('2012-08-03')];
$new = [new Date('2012-08-01'), new Date('2012-08-06')];

$old2 = $.map($old, function(el, idx) {
   for (var i in $new)
   {
      if ($new[i].getTime() == el.getTime()) return null;
   }
   return el;
});

$new2 = $.map($new, function(el, idx) {
   for (var i in $old)
   {
      if ($old[i].getTime() == el.getTime()) return null;
   }
   return el;
});

$final = $.merge($old2, $new2);
```

This works, but it seems to be kinda nooby and i guess inperformat too?
Another try i made was this:

```
for (var i in $new)
{
   var found = false;

   for (var j in $old)
   {
      if ($old[j].getTime() == $new[i].getTime())
      {
         found = true;
         $old = $old.splice(j, 1);
      }
   }

   if (found)
   {
      $new = $new.splice(i, 1);
   }
}

$final = $.merge($old, $new);
```

But this does not work at all. How to do it correctly and performant?

Comment: Don't use for-in-loops on arrays

Comment: Even with a typical for loop i cannot get it. The matches are detected, but the splice seems to fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript) or [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/840781/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

This should work, assuming you want them ordered:

```
$old = [new Date('2012-08-01'), new Date('2012-08-02'), new Date('2012-08-03')];
$new = [new Date('2012-08-01'), new Date('2012-08-06')];

var second = $old.concat($new);
var sorted_second = second.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                         // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < second.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_second[i + 1] != sorted_second[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_second[i]);
    }
}
```

Some of this code was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array), just in case you need more depth into the sorting

Comment: Sorting on Date objects fails. Thats why for some reason this solution does not work. I'm yet investigating and would appreciate any suggestion that may improve or solve my problem.